# Setting String Values Across Pages in WP7 App

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'll try my best to explain this without speaking too much about the specific content and purpose of the app.  I'll just say on the main page there are 3 empty "slots" for items you can select to occupy them.  When you click on one, it takes you to a separate page that let's you select a specific item for that slot.  Here is the code to better explain:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstSelectionName}" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstSelectionType}" />
  <HyperlinkButton Content="Choose First Option" 
                   Name="firstHyperLink" 
                   NavigateUri="/Pages/FirstChoices.xaml" 
                   />

  <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondSelectionName}" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondSelectionType}" />
  <HyperlinkButton Content="Choose Second Option" 
                   Name="secondHyperLink" 
                   NavigateUri="/Pages/SecondChoices.xaml" 
                   />

  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThirdSelectionName}" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThirdSelectionType}" />
  <HyperlinkButton Content="Choose Third Option" 
                   Name="thirdHyperLink" 
                   NavigateUri="/Pages/ThirdChoices.xaml" 
                   />
```

Here is the code behind for this XAML page:

```
 public class FirstSelection
    {
        public string FirstSelectionName { get; set; }
        public string FirstSelectionType { get; set; }            
    }

 public class SecondSelection
    {
        public string SecondSelectionName { get; set; }
        public string SecondSelectionType { get; set; }            
    }

 public class ThirdSelection
    {
        public string ThirdSelectionName { get; set; }
        public string ThirdSelectionType { get; set; }            
    }
```

On the selection pages an XML file is looped through and saved into new instances of a class.  When the user selects a certain option from that list with a button press, I want to set the corresponding slot on the main page equal to that selection.  Here is an example of the first slots selection page:

```
<ListBox Name="firstOptionsList">                
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button BorderThickness="3"
                            Click="setSelectedToFirst">                            
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Name="nameTextBlock" 
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                       />
                            <TextBlock Name="typeTextBlock" 
                                       Text="{Binding Type}" 
                                       /> 
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>                        
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

And finally the code behind for the selectin page:

```
public FirstOptionsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => firstList.ItemsSource = firstdata));

        WebClient firstWebClient = new WebClient();

        firstWebClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(first_DownloadStringCompleted);
        firstWebClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.website.com/firstoptions.xml"));
    }


    void first_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            return;

        XElement xmlitem = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

        var firstdata = new List<FirstOptionsClass>();

        foreach (XElement item in xmlitem.Elements("entry"))
        {
            var name = item.Element("name");
            var namevalue = (name == null) ? null : name.Value;
            var type = item.Element("type");
            var typevalue = (type == null) ? null : type.Value;              

            firstdata.Add
                (new FirstOptionsClass
                    {
                        Name = namevalue,
                        Type = typevalue,                           
                    }
                );
        }

        firstList.ItemsSource = firstdata;
    }

    public class FirstOptionsClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }            
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable firstdata { get; set; }

    private void setSelectedToFirst(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //THIS IS THE PART WHERE I'M NOT SURE HOW TO SET FirstOptionsClass Name = FirstSelectionName on the MainPage.xaml
    }
```

See the comment line in the click event for my main problem.  How to I set these values equal to eachother across these pages?  I know it may look like a mess here so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

TBH I'm not sure what you want to do. What fires setSelectedToFirst?

Anyways, to save some data and read it during app's lifycycle you can use [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: The button click by the user on a certain item fires setSelectedToFirst.

Comment: you have a few options to save what user click. one of them is use IsolatedStorageSettings. You use it like colletion + needs to be saved. There are a lot of examples http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-application-settings. Also you can have a singleton in App.xaml.cs where you save user's choice. var myApp = (App)Application.Current; myApp.Singleton;